# ruby vocabulary library

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vocabulary

Is there a vocabulary library that can recognize different forms as one word?
Like this:

```
Built, Builds, Building  => Build
Ate, Eaten, Eats, Eating => Eat
Tables                   => Table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Porter Stemmer for Ruby](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/ruby.txt) with description/explanation [here](http://blog.saush.com/2009/02/08/word-stemming-in-ruby/)

Comment: I checked this library, it doesn't recognize the words 'ate' and 'eaten'. Are you sure that library work?

Comment: No I'm not sure, I've never used it... but I'm not aware of any other stemming libraries in Ruby

Answer (score 2):

This one isn't specifically, for Ruby, but the [Wordlists project](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/12dicts-readme.html) has a dictionary called 2of12inf, which includes these different forms (inflections) of words.

Comment: In 2of12inf.txt file how to see the connection between 'ate' and 'eat'?